# Failed to remove all minimum elements in a list in a Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

```py
list1=[1,2,3,2,2,1,1,1,1]
for i in list1:
    if(i==min(list1)):
        list1.remove(i)
print(list1)
```

ABOVE IS THE CODE WHICH IS WRITTEN IN A PYTHON TO SHOW MY PROBLEM .

As you can see in above code of python ,In a given list there is a 1 which is a minimum element in a list and it occurs 5 times in a list .I want a list in which all 1 should be absent ,So I used here a min function in a python to find a minimum element in a list and by using for loop I removed all minimum elements . But when I ran this code , output which was very unexpected to me was a list which still contains 1 .

Comment: The issue is that after removing the current value `for loop` jumps to the next index of the updated list, i.e. skips and doesn't check `the next one` value.

Answer (score 2):

Do not try to modify a list while iterating over it. This will cause problems. Consider what happens if we do this with your example list: `[1, 2, 3, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1]`.

The elements that are considered:

```
[1, 2, 3, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1]
 ^
```

Because this is removed, we skip the `2`.

```
[1, 2, 3, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1]
       ^

[1, 2, 3, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1]
          ^

[1, 2, 3, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1]
             ^

[1, 2, 3, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1]
                ^

[1, 2, 3, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1]
                      ^
```

Every time we remove an element, we're not evaluating the next element on the next iteration. End result?

```
[2, 3, 2, 2, 1, 1]
```

The other danger is that you're modifying list, but each iteration recalculates `min(list1)`. This value can *change* because you've removed elements from `list`. Your example list doesn't trigger this because there is always a `1` left at the end, but what if you test with something like: `[1, 2, 3, 2, 2, 2]`?

On the first iteration `1` is the minimum element, but on subsequent iterations, `2` is.

Instead build a *new* list with the elements you want. You can then assign it back to the same variable name.

```py
list1 = [1, 2, 3, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1]
m = min(list1)
list1 = [x for x in list1 if x != m]
```

Comment: Thank You , You cleared my doubt very well.

Comment: Best way to say thank you on SO is to accept whichever answer you feel has best answered your question.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the next code snippet for that purpose:

```
list1 = [1, 2, 3, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1]
min_element = min(list1)
new_list = [x for x in list1 if x != min_element]
print(new_list)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem is that you misunderstand your code. Instead you could use the following code:

```py
old_list = [1, 2, 3, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1]

min_value = min(old_list)
new_list = [x for x in old_list if x != min_value]

print(new_list)
```

which prints:

```
[2, 3, 2, 2]
```

The above code creates a new list with all of the elements of the old list *except* for those which are equal to `min_value` (i.e. all elements except for 1).

---

I hope this helps.

Comment: `List.remove` doesnt require the index to the element to be removed.

Comment: Sorry @MátéJuhász that was sloppy answer writing on my part. I think that's fixed now.